# POwer pivot Calculated field using aggregates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a source table loking like this

| Date | Measure Name | Measure value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | Revenue | 1250 |
| 01/01/2020 | Sales number | 43 |
| 01/01/2020 | Costs | 1000 |
| 01/02/2020 | Revenue | 4500 |
| 01/02/2020 | Sales number | 590 |
| 01/02/2020 | Costs | 3420 |

I create a power pivot table, putting measure name column in ROW field of Power Pivot, which gives the following result :

|  | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Revenue | 1250 | 4500 |
| Costs | 1000 | 3420 |
| Sales number | 43 | 590 |

Now I need to calculate Revenue per sale (revenue/sales number). But since revenue and sales number are presented in a single column in source table, they are not available for calculation.
How can I solve this using DAX? I understand that this could be solved using power query, but that is not a preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

With a new measure, perhaps:

```
Revenue per Sale :=
VAR Revenue =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Measure value] ), Table1[Measure Name] = "Revenue" )
VAR Sales =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[Measure value] ),
        Table1[Measure Name] = "Sales number"
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( Revenue, Sales )
```